# Non-backtracking regex hangs node on strings with newlines

Tags: javascript, regex

I have no idea why this hangs the javascript engine but it does. Anyone else have a clue?

```
function isEnglish(text) {
    const checker = /^(\p{Emoji}|\p{ASCII})+$/u;
    return !!checker.exec(text.replace(/\\n/g, ""));
}

text = `
RT @PROMOSIGROUP: FOLL TWITTER
3K:20rb
5k:30rb
10K:50rb
Foll IG aktif WW
100F:15rb
500F:50rb
1K:100rb
Jual Akun Twitter+IG
081327927525/…`

isEnglish(text);
```

Ok, figured it out, the "…" character causes the regex engine to spin. Anyone know why this might be?

Comment: There is backtracking in this pattern because the `\p{ASCII}` and `\p{Emoji}` both match digits from 0 to 9 and `#` and `*`. Alternatives should not match at the same location. You might just use a character class though, `/^[\p{Emoji}\p{ASCII}]+$/u`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're `isEnglish()` test is supposed to return `true` when the source text consists solely of:

- US-ASCII characters,
- Emoji (not sure why this would count as "english", but whatever), and
- Punctuation

and `false` otherwise.

I might point out that US-ASCII covers U+0000 to U+007F: that includes the *C0 Control Characters* (U+0000 to U+001F), as well as [DEL] (U+007F), none of which, save whitespace, are actual characters.

But, you're  making a mountain out of a molehill: it will be much faster (and clearer) to just search for the first character that's **not** part of your desired alphabet:

```js
function isEnglish(s) {
 return !rxIsNonEnglishAlphabet.test(s);
}

// -------------------------------------------------------
// this regular expression matches characters that are NOT
// * Whitespace
// * US-ASCII (u+0000 through U+007F)
// * Emoji
// * Punctuation
// -------------------------------------------------------
const rxIsNonEnglishAlphabet = /[^\s\p{ASCII}\p{Emoji}\p{Punctuation}]/u;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. The reason for including control characters / emojis / unicode punctuation is that I'm filtering tweets and don't want to drop them just because they have a smiley face or a linefeed.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my regex turns into a big backtracking bug even though there isn't anything obvious to me that would cause that. My function now looks much different to get it to work:

```
function isEnglish(text) {
    const ascii = /\p{ASCII}/ug;
    const emoji = /\p{Emoji}/ug;
    const punct = /\p{Punctuation}/ug;
    text = text.replace(ascii, "");
    text = text.replace(emoji, "");
    text = text.replace(punct, "");
    return text.length === 0;
}
```